# Can I transfer credit card debt to someone else?

Tags: credit-card, debt

My wife used my credit card in her business and used 20,000 (AMEX CARD) and then she couldn’t pay off the debt. Now it’s hurting my credit and we wanted to move the debt from me to her. Taking into consideration that I admit that I allowed her to use the card and she admit that she used it on her business.

Comment: OK.  What's your question?

Comment: is it possible to transfer credit debt?

Comment: I think the only way to get rid of a specific credit card's debt is to pay it off.  Taking out a loan and using that money to pay the card effectively transfers the debt from one location to another.

Comment: @RonJohn That’s an answer.

Comment: @BenMiller it's an educated hypothesis.  There might actually be a way to directly transfer CC debt.

Comment: @RonJohn If you aren’t sure that your answer is correct, that’s all the more reason to post it as an answer. That way, other users can downvote it if it is wrong. :)

Answer (score 8):

> we wanted to move the debt from me to her

The only way to get rid of a specific credit card's debt is to pay it off. Having her take out a loan and using that money to pay the card effectively transfers the debt from your card to hers.

Answer (score 6):

According to [here](https://www.finder.com/balance-transfers-with-joint-primary-cardholders-guide), some credit cards allow you to transfer balances between authorized users/joint account holders.  However, American Express is not one of them.

You could try transferring the balance to a credit card that does; preferably one that gives you a 0% interest rate on balance transfers for 12 to 18 months.

Comment: I would note that a balance transfer typically costs about 3% in balance transfer fees.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK there are a couple of credit cards available which offer a 0% rate on money transfers. Other cards also allow money transfers, however tend to charge a punitive rate of interest so I wouldn't suggest considering those as serious options. Your wife could take out a 0% money transfer credit card (if there's one available in your country), use a money transfer to get cash out of the card into her bank account, and then give you the money to pay off your cards. The end result being the debt transferred to a card in your wife's name. As with all credit cards, the actual amount you will be able to do this with will depend on a number of factors